# GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found when I archive an app

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps

I used in GoogleMap my project,There is no problem when I use the simulator.But when i archive the project ,I'm getting a build error - GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h file not found. But i change the Bulid Configuration into Debug (Edit Scheme -> Archive -> Build Configuration ->Debug)is no problem.Can someone help me,What reason is this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: It happens sometimes with cocoapods, for no particular reason. Just Build again and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks  for your respondse,but  I didn't use cocoapods,I try again for several times But it doesn't work.

Comment: I feel very confused, When I use the simulator to run the it, there is no  problems, But I when i pack it to ipa file it appear such mistakes.